# Why am I getting a "lvalue required as unary & operand" error?

Tags: c

I'm working on a function that inserts a value in a binary search tree, I wrote this code:

```
// this is my decalarations if its relevent
typedef struct element* tree;
typedef struct element
{  
    type data;
    tree right;
    tree left;
} noed;

tree rightSon(tree head)
{
    return (head->right);
}

void insert(tree* a,int val)
{
     if(!empty(*a)) {
         if((*a)->data>val) {    
             if(!empty(leftSon(*a)))
                  insert(&leftSon(*a),val); // error here leftson return a tree
            else {
             (*a)->left=newNoed(val);
            }
         }
         else if((*a)->data<val) {
              if(!empty(rightSon(*a)))
                  insert(&rightSon(*a),val); //same error here
            else 
             (*a)->right=newNoed(val);
         }
         else printf("value already exist!\n");
    }
    else {
        *a=newNoed(val);
    }
}
```

I solved the problem by declaring local variables of type `tree` then assigning the values to them like this:

```
tree lson;
lson=leftson(*a);
insert(&lson,val);
```

But I still don't get what was the problem in the first place.

Comment: `insert(&leftSon(*a),val);` even if it worked what do you expect would happen here? After insertion where result will be stored?

Comment: @EricPostpischil i tested it and it gave me the correct result are you sure?

Comment: @RafikBouloudene: Nevermind, `insert` is not inserting its first parameter in the tree, just using it to find the place to insert. That can work with a temporary object. There is no reason for it, though; you can get rid of the `leftSon` function and just replace `insert(&leftSon(*a),val)` with `insert(&(*a)->left, val)`.

Comment: hiding a pointer in a typedef is always a bad idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the function `leftSon` (and `rightSon`) has the return type `tree`. That is it returns a temporary object. You may not apply the operator & to a temporary object like in this statement

```
insert(&leftSon(*a),val);
```

You could write the code without calling the functions leftSon or rightSon like

```
 if(!empty(rightSon(*a)))
     insert( &(*a)->right ,val);
```

In fact the if-else statements like this

```
         if(!empty(leftSon(*a)))
              insert(&leftSon(*a),val); // error here leftson return a tree
        else 
        {
         (*a)->left=newNoed(val);
        
        }
```

are redundant. Instead of them you could just write

```
insert( &(*a)->left, val );
```

and

```
insert( &(*a)->right, val );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `rightSon` function is returning the *value* of the pointer object stored at `head->right`.  You can't take the address of a value.

What you want to do instead is have `rightSon` return the *address* of `head->right` which can then be passed directly to `insert`.

So change `rightSon` to return the address:

```
tree *rightSon(tree head)
{
    return &head->right;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
insert(rightSon(*a),val);
```

`leftSon` presumably has the same issue, so make a similar change for that.

Also, hiding a pointer behind a `typedef` is considered bad practice as it's no longer obvious by just looking at the code that a variable of that type is a pointer and can cause confusion to the reader.